# For what odd primes $p$ does $p - 2 \mid p + 2$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

For what odd primes $p$ does $p - 2 \mid p + 2$?

For example, $p = 3$.

> Are there any others?

Comment: if you know the answer why do you ask?

Comment: @TsemoAristide, mostly for my own benefit.  Most of my questions here stem from considerations related to some problems in number theory.  That is why, if I know of an answer to an existing question of mine, I post it right away.

Comment: This is only to do feedback about it, from my viewpoint: that could be interesting ask about a possible generalization. I don't know if the generalization in the literature, but maybe is feasible. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, @user243301.  I will keep that in mind.

Comment: As [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2216759/242) in the dupe $\,p-2\mid p+2\iff p-2\mid 2+2\,$ by mod divisibility reduction.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Notice that $\frac{p+2}{p-2}=1+\frac{4}{p-2}$, which is less than $2$  for $p>6$.

So we must only check $p=3$ and $5$ and only the first works.

Answer (score 5):

We can look at the problem for any $p\ge2$, regardless of prime or not. Then taking $a:=p-2$ and $b:=p+2$, we can see that $a=b-4$, so $a\mid b \implies a\mid 4$, giving $a=\{1,2,4\}$ as the only possibilities, and thus $p=\{3,4,6\}$ as the corresponding solutions.

Of course only one of these is prime: $p=3$.

Answer (score 3):

Notice that
$$\gcd(p - 2, p + 2) = \gcd(4, p + 2) = \gcd(4, p - 2)$$
so that if $p - 2 \mid p + 2$, then
$$\gcd(p - 2, p + 2) = p - 2 = \gcd(4, p - 2).$$

Since $p$ is an odd prime then $p \geq 3$ and either $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ or $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$.

Consequently, equality can only occur in
$$\gcd(p - 2, p + 2) = p - 2 = \gcd(4, p - 2)$$
when $p = 3$.

**QED**